# EE 1.13.1 Url Rewrites Not Working.. Why will they not index?

Tags: url, indexing, url-rewrite, ee-1.13

This is a clean install of EE 1.13.1 not an upgraded site.

I am facing this issue with a group of skus in my catalog...

> `www.MYSITE.com/catalog/product/view/id/189576/s/**url-key**/category/293/`

I have checked the rewrite tables for this and there are no rewrites for it. It is as if it is keeping that url, and will not index it to a clean url.

Secondly there are products like this:

> `www.mysite.com/catalog/product/view/id/188662`

(same product, both urls work)
This once again has a valid URL key that is not a duplicate, and yet can not index. Why?

Comment: How did you create or import your products?

Comment: They were created with uRapidflow by Unirgy, but so were all the rest and those are indexing fine. Thats what makes it so weird

Comment: Hm, uRapidflow advertises as being compatible with upto EE 1.14. Can you check your catalog's url key table and tell me if there's anything in there?

Comment: Unirgy was not being entirely honest there. They were completely unaware of the complex URL changes in 1.13, until I had reported it in tickets. (For example you can no longer export product URL because there is no value for it in 1.13)

Secondly the other day I placed a ticket asking for 1.14/1.9 support and they stated they would be reviewing it in the next few weeks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reindex your URL rewrites. You are able to do it using shell in Magento EE 13+

```
cd [magento_root]/shell
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
```

If it didn't help:
Try to open some of the products in admin panel for editing and try to save it. Then, try to check the product's URL in the rewrite tables once again. Maybe the reason is the products were imported incorrectly somehow.
If that way is solving your issue : You can make a script - just get products collection and save each product without making changes

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach ($products as $_product) {
    $_product->save();
}
```

Also, you can add a try..catch structure in case if you have a problem with the product's saving.

Comment: Yeah no thats not it, the site has been indexed 100s of times and even specifically that URL. Sorry if I portrayed it as it was not. The point is only these products (around 3000) are having that issue despite multiple reindexes..

Comment: Try to open some of the products in admin panel for editing and try to save it. Then, try to check the product's URL in the rewrite tables once again. Maybe the reason is the products were imported incorrectly somehow.

Comment: you could be right, yesterday I edited the url-key for one product and that product did get indexed with the new clean url. Can you edit your answer to mirror your second comment?

Comment: help me @ https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/210130/57334